# Cartoon about a dinosaur that eats clouds?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, dinosaurs

I've been trying to remember the name of a cartoon I watched around 2010 about a dinosaur that eats clouds. He lives on the clouds and comes down during the day, where he meets his friends, and one of them was a pig, unless I'm mistaken. He is pretty big and I vaguely remember his friends using his tail as a slide as well.

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me out here!

Update: I think it's a dragon.

Comment: The cloud worm? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Q4MI7UWosA

Comment: @Valorum unfortunately no

Comment: Dibo ? https://youtu.be/7IszdJEimLc?t=87

Comment: @Yaroslav Kornachevskyi OMG thank you!!!! That's the one!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Dibo the gift dragon**](https://ocon.fandom.com/wiki/Dibo_the_Gift_Dragon)

"Meet Dibo, a kindhearted dragon with a love of learning, friendship, and magical adventure!"

[image]